# Help finding 16 more critical points of a vector valued function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \supseteq G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}?$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

So, I was going through *A First Course in Analysis* by John B. Conway, Springer, first edition (2018) and came across this question in a section *(6.6 to be precise)* talking about the critical points of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$;

> Let $\Omega = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1\}$ and define $f$ on $\Omega$ by $f(x,y,z) = \sin(\pi x)^2 + \cos(\pi y)^2 - z^2$. Find all the critical points of $f$ in $\Omega$ and give the nature of each whenever you can.

According to some of my friends and my professor, there are supposedly **25 critical points**. However, in all my efforts I have only been able to uncover 9 such points. Below is a summation of results of my efforts, and what I know;

> Let $\Omega$ and $f$ be defined as above. Then to find our critical points, we must find all $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\nabla f(a) = 0$, where $\nabla f(a) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a), \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a) \right)$.
>
> So, we can find that $$\partial_x f = 2\pi \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x) $$
>   $$ \partial_y f = -2\pi \sin(\pi y)\cos(\pi y)$$
>   $$ \partial_z f = -2z $$
>   and setting each $\partial f = 0$, we can find that 
>   $$\partial_x f = 0\text{ when } x = 0, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}$$ 
>   $$\partial_y f = 0\text{ when } y = 0, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}$$ 
>   $$\partial_z f = 0\text{ when } z = 0$$
>
> So, our possible critical points are \begin{array}[ccc] ((0,0,0) & (0,\frac{1}{2},0) & (0,-\frac{1}{2},0) \\ (\frac{1}{2},0,0) & (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) & (\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0)\\ (-\frac{1}{2},0,0) & (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) & (-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0)\end{array}
>
> So, by the second derivative test, we can determine the nature of the critical points listed above;
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(0,0,0) \right) = 8\pi^4 \implies (0,0,0) \text{ is a local min.} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(0,\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = -8\pi^4 \implies (0,\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a saddle point} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(0,-\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = -8\pi^4 \implies (0,-\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a saddle point} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(\frac{1}{2},0,0) \right) = -8\pi^4 \implies (\frac{1}{2},0,0) \text{ is a saddle point} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = 8\pi^4 \implies (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a local min.} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = 8\pi^4 \implies (\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a local min.} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(-\frac{1}{2},0,0) \right) = -8\pi^4 \implies (-\frac{1}{2},0,0) \text{ is a saddle point} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = -8\pi^4 \implies (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a saddle point} $$
>   $$ \text{det}\left( D^2f(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) \right) = 8\pi^4 \implies (-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) \text{ is a local max.} $$
>   given that $\partial_{xx}f(0,0,0) = \partial_{xx}f(0,\frac{1}{2},0) = \partial_{xx}f(0,-\frac{1}{2},0) = 2\pi^2 > 0$ and $\partial_{xx}f(\frac{1}{2},0,0) = \partial_{xx}f(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) = \partial_{xx}f(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) = \partial_{xx}f(-\frac{1}{2},0,0) = \partial_{xx}f(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0) = \partial_{xx}f(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0) = -2\pi^2 < 0$.

And one last thing to clarify a little more of what I think I understand about this:
So to the best of my knowledge, the second derivative test involves using the Hesian of $f(a)$, which means just finding the determinant of the matrix created from the second derivatives of $f$. Although, I haven't heard the word *Hesian* anywhere other than online once I started looking for help.
Also, one of my friends said that due to the fact that $z$ must always be zero to have a critical point there, something special happens, but I don't understand *EXACTLY* what he meant by that. It makes sense but still doon't know how to put it down on paper.

So finally, here are my questions:

**1.)** How would I go about finding the other 16 critical points (if there are truly that many)? Does it involve looking at the eigenvalues of each $D^2f(a)$ where $a$ is a potential critical point?

**2.)** In the future, how would I know that there even are that many more critical points to the function? Does it have to do with the cyclic nature of sine and cosine?

I know this was a long post but I've been working all week on this and just want to understand what I need to do! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you! I figure what I've done thus far is good, but all my colleagues keep saying there are more, but I can't figure how that is even possible.

Comment: About the only thing I can think of is if it's actually $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$ and we look at the boundary with Lagrange multipliers. But then ... we get $24$ new boundary critical points, not $16$. Eight points with all of $x,y,z$ nonzero, four with $x=0$, four with $y=0$, four with $z=0$, four with $z=0$ and one of $x,y$ zero.

Comment: @jmerry I hadn't thought of that. Maybe my colleagues thought it was supposed to be $\leq 1$ instead of $< 1$. I'll have to ask them again. Thank you though for this! I'll be sure to look into this way of solving it. Maybe parts of it hold the rest of the solution they were thinking of.